# Convert 24 hr to 12 hr in Android

Tags: android

Hello I'd like to convert 24 hr to 12 hr in Android. The time comes from user input in the timepicker dialog, then display it in a textview. If the user clicks on the PM button in the picker dialog, it should automatically display that in a textview. For examaple, the user clicks on 3:00 AM, it should display in the textview as 3:00 AM, while another user clicks on 3:00 PM, it should display in the textview 3:00 PM not 15:00. Any help please?

Please do check the code I have below:

```
            public void onTimeSet( TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
                int selectedMinute ) {
            // Gets current time
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            hour = selectedHour;
            minute = selectedMinute;


            // set waking time into textview

           String getWT = wakingtime.getText().toString();
           wakingtime.setText( new StringBuilder().append( pad( hour ))
                    .append( ":" ).append( pad( minute ))); 


            // Assign hour set in the picker
            c.set( Calendar.HOUR, selectedHour );
            c.set( Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute );

            // Have Calendar calculate the substraction of hours and minutes
            c.add( Calendar.HOUR, SUB_HOUR );
            c.add( Calendar.MINUTE, SUB_MINUTE );

            // Get the hour and the minute calculated
            hour = c.get( Calendar.HOUR );
            minute = c.get( Calendar.MINUTE );
```

I beg your pardon if you don't see any formatting..

Comment: @njzk2 Hi thanks for the reply. Can you give me some codes how to get started with simpledateformatter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changue this:

```
    wakingtime.setText( new StringBuilder().append( pad( hour ))
                        .append( ":" ).append( pad( minute )));
```

By this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if(hour>=12){                      
    sb.append(hour-12).append( ":" ).append(minute).append(" PM");
}else{
    sb.append(hour).append( ":" ).append(minute).append(" AM");
}
wakingtime.setText(sb);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
String s;
if(hour>=12){                      
     s=String.formate((hour-12)+":"+minute+"PM");
 }else{
      s=String.formate(hour+":"+minute+"AM");
 }

 txtview.setText(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    scheduleTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(activity, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {

                    String choosedHour = "";
                    String choosedMinute = "";
                    String choosedTimeZone = "";
                    if(selectedHour > 12){
                        choosedTimeZone = "PM";
                       selectedHour = selectedHour - 12;
                        if(selectedHour < 10){
                            choosedHour = "0"+selectedHour;
                        }else{
                            choosedHour = ""+selectedHour;
                        }
                    }else{
                        choosedTimeZone = "AM";
                        if(selectedHour < 10){
                            choosedHour = "0"+selectedHour;
                        }else{
                            choosedHour = ""+selectedHour;
                        }
                    }

                    if(selectedMinute < 10){
                        choosedMinute = "0"+selectedMinute;
                    }else{
                        choosedMinute= ""+selectedMinute;
                    }

                    scheduleTime.setText(choosedHour + ":" + choosedMinute +" "+choosedTimeZone);
                    //scheduleTime.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                    //scheduleTime.setText( strHrsToShow+":"+datetime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+" "+am_pm );
                }
            }, hour, minute+30, false);//Yes 24 hour time
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();
        }
    });
```

I have used this logic to solve mine.